# Error linea PHP comillas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un error en las comillas de esta sentencia de MySQL en PHP, ya que el LIMIT no le coge como tal, espero vuestra ayuda.

```
$sqlP = 'SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE 
id_publicacion='.$row["id_publicacion"].' LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: de donde obtienes row?

Comment: $sqlP = "SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE 
id_publicacion='.$row["id_publicacion"].' LIMIT 1"; y si pruebas de este modo?

Comment: ¿Qué estás usando? ¿Mysqli o PDO/mysql? La respuesta "mala-pero-correcta" podría ser `$sqlP = 'SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE 
id_publicacion = \'' . $row["id_publicacion"] . '\' LIMIT 1';` o bien `$sqlP = "SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE 
id_publicacion = '${row["id_publicacion"]}' LIMIT 1';` siempre y cuando `$row["id_publicacion"]` sea entero o cadena. Pero aunque soluciona parcialmente tu problema no es una solución correcta porque sufre problemas de [**inyección SQL**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL).

Comment: El error no es la consulta en sí, sino lo que hay en `$row['id_publicacion']`, que podría ser cualquier cosa. Si hubiera un valor numérico, la consulta se crearía sin error. Por ejemplo: `$row=array("id_publicacion"=>"1"); $sqlP = 'SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE 
id_publicacion='.$row["id_publicacion"].' LIMIT 1';` el resultado sería: **`SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE 
id_publicacion=1 LIMIT 1`**, pero si hubiera un dato extraño: `$row=array("id_publicacion"=>"1'");` la consulta sería errónea: `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id_publicacion=1' LIMIT 1`

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar, me da este error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /storage/ssd2/319/6310319/public_html/componentes/inmobiliaria/view.php on line 35`

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en las comillas simples donde declaraste tu consulta. Recuerda que el uso de estas es para solo cadenas, en caso de tener alguna variable dentro de la cadena se utilizan las comillas dobles y todo lo que este dentro incluido dicha variable iria con comillas simples.

Tu consulta debería quedar de esta forma:

```
$sqlP = "SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE 
id_publicacion='.$row["id_publicacion"].' LIMIT 1";
```

Mas info haciendo clic [aca](https://platzi.com/php/tutoriales/diferencia-entre-comillas-simples-y-comillas-dobles-en-php/)

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar, me da este error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /storage/ssd2/319/6310319/public_html/componentes/inmobiliaria/view.php on line 35`

Comment: Intentaste sacando los puntos de concatenación en tu varibale `.$row["id_publicacion"].` ?