# Syntax error PHP ""

Tags: php, mysql

```
// retrieve selected results from database and display them on page
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM publicaciones LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $sqlP = "SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE id_publicacion='.$row["id_publicacion"].' LIMIT 1";
    $resultP = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlP);
```

Tengo este codigo donde en la linea: `$sqlP = "SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE id_publicacion='.$row["id_publicacion"].' LIMIT 1";`

Me da el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ...

El caso es que no veo ningún fallo de comillas ni nada. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, un saludo.

Comment: [Ya habías preguntado algo parecido aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177526/29967).  ¿Por qué no muestras lo que hay en `$row` mediante un `var_dump($row);`? Si en el array hay datos con valores como `'` o como `"` u otros datos que trunquen la cadena podrás tener una SQL errónea. Y si hay datos manipulados por hackers podrás tener una **Inyección SQL**. Construir tu consulta así es demasiado peligroso, deberás usar consultas preparadas y te evitarás perder el tiempo con este tipo de errores. Otra cosa extraña es lanzar una consulta dentro de un bucle... quizá se pueda optimizar tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas $row["id_publicacion"] y el operador . para concatenar el string, debes poner el mismo tipo de comillas que al principio de la select y usar otras comillas o escaparlas para las comillas de delimitación del campo.

Puedes cambiar la select así

```
$sqlP = "SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE id_publicacion='".$row["id_publicacion"]." ' LIMIT 1";
```

Pero no es recomendable que hagas así las consultas a base de datos. O no por lo menos cuando en la consulta introduzcas datos introducidos por el usuario porque podrían hacerte sql injection.

Comment: Buenas Iker! Es que lo que quiero hacer es mostrar unas imagenes que tengo en "coleccionPublicaciones" relacionadas con la tabla "publicaciones", entonces la fk es id_publicacion, y solo se me ha ocurrido esta forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Pero si lo haces así, lo que te sobra totalmente son los puntos . junto a la variable $row["id_publicacion"] porque te lo va a añadir en la select. Si es un fk entonces no hay problema en hacerlo sin prepare.

Answer (score 0):

Las comillas externas (en php) deben ser diferentes de las de la sentencia Mysql (internas en la query)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones LIMIT '".$this_page_first_result."','". $results_per_page."' ";

$sqlP = "SELECT * FROM coleccionPublicaciones WHERE id_publicacion='".$row["id_publicacion"]."' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Esto me funciona correctamente...es en otra linea el fallo, lo he dejado bien explicado

Comment: Es el mismo tipo de construcción, lo puse en la primera aunque te va a funcionar al ser valores númericos, pero es conveniente mantener la estructura entre llamar al texto y las variables para evitar errores de sintaxis.